# null value not found in database

Tags: mysql, null, innodb

I have an InnoDB table with a column called 'status'. This can be filled with either 'succes' or 'special', or with NULL, when the code ran an exception.

I have a cronjob which looks at this table and tries to reprocess rows with a status other than 'succes' or 'special'. I noticed however, that it doesn't work.

So I queried the table with the following query:

SELECT * FROM master_innodb.some_table WHERE `status` != 'succes' AND `status` != 'special';

It returns 0 rows.

When I changed the row that I expected it to return from status NULL to an empty field, the query returned this row.

Can someone explain this?

Regards,

Matthijs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think reckon you could do with understanding a little bit more about what a NULL value represents in a MySQL database. NULL can be a confusing beast at the best of times. From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html):

> The NULL value can be surprising until you get used to it.
>   Conceptually, NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated
>   somewhat differently from other values.

So NULL pretty much means 'an absence of data'. So when you specify a predicate of:

```
status != 'success' AND status != 'special'
```

Then the row with NULL in the `status` column is not returned because we don't know whether or not the row with the NULL `status` is equal to 'succes' or equal to 'special'. Hence it is not returned.

You could try this instead the get rows to reprocess in your CRON job:

```
SELECT * FROM master_innodb.some_table WHERE status is null;
```